# Animate replacing widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I am replacing widgets to navigate. using bottom navigation bar

[Following this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YGlCNPpohz4&t=443s)

so when an item is pressed on the nav bar, basically the widget that scaffold's body contains is replaced with another. So is it possible to animate this change ? if so how ? I am a very beginner in flutter.

Comment: see `AnimatedSwitcher`